# why arent tabs of bootstrap working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#songs">Songs</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Video</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="uploaded-image-ct">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Upload image
      </button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="songs" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="video" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input placeholder="Paste YouTube link here" type="text">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

[image: this picture of the code and design it makes]

the video section should show youtube which there on html but not on the page.

i checked whether jquery is loaded ahead of bootstrap.js.. But still it is not working. Turns out the tab button is not working like it should. although when u click on image button image section will be shown. Is it the problem only with input tag?

Comment: We won't know unless you post the code, not just the image.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Consider posting a [code snippet](http://i.imgur.com/YrYSIlG.png) (there is a snippet widget on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1):

Your video pill has the following:

```
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Video</a>
```

but the id of the tab you are trying to link it to is:

```
<div id="video" class="tab-pane fade">
```

you need to change the pill to the same id

```
 <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#video">Video</a>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#songs">Songs</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#video">Video</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="uploaded-image-ct">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Upload image
      </button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="songs" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="video" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input placeholder="Paste YouTube link here" type="text">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#songs">Songs</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#video">Video</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="uploaded-image-ct">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Upload image
      </button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="songs" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="video" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input placeholder="Paste YouTube link here" type="text">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

jQuery needs the correct `href` in the anchor tag which you have in the tab that points to the correct `tab-pane`.

You were using:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#songs">Songs</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Video</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You need to have the `href` of the `Video` point to `#video` like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#songs">Songs</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#video">Video</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ha ha @Jeremy Iglehart - I already posted that - its a race!! :))